# Screen keeps black after official upate for Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: standby, ota-update, samsung-galaxy-s-3

A few days ago, the phone got an OTA update (build number: IMM76D.I9300XXALF6). After that the phone got unusable: Once the screen goes out, I cannot wake up the device anymore. The only exception is when it's connected to my laptop, then I can wake it up any time.

I already tried resetting it to factory defaults, but it did not help.

Any ideas? Or should I send the phone back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sent it back for repair. Main board was exchanged and now it's working fine with the latest version. Just bad luck I guess.